# Is it possible to define the maximum voize computer can output in Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, volume-control

I'm living in an apartment building and it is forbidden to make hard noise at nights. Is it possible to configure Ubuntu such that the speaker won't output noise in too high volume at nights?

Answer (score 0):

Dial down the master volume control linked from the panel (as opposed to volume controls in apps, such as browsers), or lower the master volume in ALSA https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer

If you have a desktop you can also a volume control on the audio cable like http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/390497226138?lpid=82 (not my item) to reduce to sound level reaching the speakers - not practical with laptops, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the master volume automatically e.g. via a cronjob that runs a script.
The script would probably look sth like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# limit volume to 20%
# full path is used because the path variable might not contain /usr/bin/ when run from cron job
/usr/bin/pactl set-sink-volume 0 20%
```

save this as `/var/beQuiet.sh` for example

and the cron line (run `crontab -e` and add it at the end)

```
0 21 * * *   /bin/bash /var/beQuiet.sh
```

to run the script every day at 9 o'clock in the evening.

Of course it would still be possible to manually set the volume higher, but at least you can no longer forget to turn it down ;)

EDIT:
if the bash script shouldn't work for you [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739390/how-to-programmatically-change-volume-in-ubuntu) has other scripts, such as a handy python script that uses the python-alsaaudio package, to set the master volume